# How do I prove the construction of a Pentadecagon for a given side length?

Tags: geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

I was recently tutoring geometry at a university. The students knew how to construct different polygons. Therefore I wanted to know how to prove the construction.

One task was constructing a pentadecagon with a given side length. The steps for the construction are in the following article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadecagon

I don't get how the circumcircle radius is deducted by the construction of the smaller pentagon. What relations exist for the circumcircle radius that are used here?
Why is the construction done the way it is?

Comment: What do you mean?  A circumcircle radius is just the radius of the circle.  the only relationship to anything that I can tell is that it is ... a radius.  And the angles are 24 degrees.

Comment: I want to know how do you get the circumcircle radius with given side length. Why is a smaller pentagon constructed as one of the steps?

Comment: What smaller pentagon?  If you want a polygon of a given side length k:  Make a polygon with a radius of 1 unit.  It will have side, s, construct a line that is $r=\frac ks$ long via.  Make a polygon with a radius of $r$.  The side of this polygon will by $s*r = s*\frac ks= k$.

Comment: pls look at the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadecagon

"Construction for a given side length" why is the construction done the way it is